After certbot renew openvidu server getToken no response
I use OV server 2.20.0
I restarted docker with:
docker restart $(docker ps -a | grep nginx | awk '{print $1}')

Restared also openvide and node.js middleware.
Before new cert everything works fine...
Any suggestion ?
Warns and error logs:

(node:703912) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Listening on port: 2020.
(node:703912) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Getting a token | {sessionName}={hang3d-matrix}
New session hang3d
Error: [object Object]
    at OpenVidu.handleError (/var/applications/kure/kure-server-client/node_modules/openvidu-node-client/lib/OpenVidu.js:694:20)
    at /var/applications/kure/kure-server-client/node_modules/openvidu-node-client/lib/Session.js:513:26
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Docker list cointainers:
docker container list
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                  PORTS     NAMES
7161cbceff66   openvidu/openvidu-coturn:5.0.0        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 months ago   Up 3 months
        openvidu_coturn_1
98dcc885dd52   openvidu/openvidu-redis:3.0.0         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 months ago   Up 3 months
        openvidu_redis_1
88ec2b99b2d5   openvidu/openvidu-proxy:7.0.0         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 months ago   Up 13 minutes
        openvidu_nginx_1
7fb2cf4f71b4   kurento/kurento-media-server:6.16.0   "/entrypoint.sh"         3 months ago   Up 3 months (healthy)     
        openvidu_kms_1
87de8a1873e4   openvidu/openvidu-call:2.20.0         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 months ago   Up 3 months
        openvidu_app_1
b0fa6b53835d   openvidu/openvidu-server:2.20.0       "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 months ago   Up 3 months
        openvidu_openvidu-server_1

Maybe i need to restart all ...
UPDATE :
I restared all docker but still not work.
I inspect  my main test kurento link on 4443 port:
net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

I just need to find who to inject new cert intro docker ...
Any suggestion where can be (right container) ...

I simple copy/override files at :
/opt/openvidu/certificates/live/domain/

But i also needed to restart dockers and node.
